# how can i connect mssql using php?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect mssql database which installed on other server. my php version in 7.1 and i already activate sqlsrv. but its showing error. I am using fastcoment's server.

```
$serverName = "22*.**.***.2";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"*********", "UID"=>"******", "PWD"=>"br&#&&**4H9q6");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

and i am getting this error

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking how to install drivers for a specific web host.

Answer (score 1):

Did you even read the page for the link the error message provided?

> The correct version of the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server is
>   required on the computer on which PHP is running. You can download all
>   supported versions of the driver for supported platforms on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: yes i read it. But i don't know how to intall in fastcomet and how..

Comment: Download the appropriate binary at link from the quoted text?  I am not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: i got the solution.. its not possible in shared hosting..